Is it possible to record the screen of Garmin avionics?
Is there built-in functionality to record the screens of Garmin avionics?  G1000, G3X, etc.  I'm trying to play back video recordings of flights and want to see what the avionics are doing while I fly.

According to this forum post on Pilots Of America (from 2010) a G1000 has the ability to log the data. Then you can upload it to cirrusreports.com, get mapping, parameter graphs and even replay the flight.
This is 14 years old and things may have changed since then, but I doubt that Garmin has removed a feature (you never know...) though you may have to find a different way to view/play back the data.
Note: no affiliation whatsoever with any of the sites mentioned, it was literally the first result of a DuckDuckGo search for "screen record Garmin G1000".
